# Obtain a Boolean from html expression Python

Tags: python, html, boolean, beautifulsoup

I wanted to assign a boolean value to this opertions:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
x = soup.find('tr')
y = x.findAll('td')
left = y[0]
```

if `assert('blah'in left['class'])` holds true -- meaning there left has a class called 'blah', then 
`return true`.

Comment: Do you mean y = x.find('td')? You're not using the value of x.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, You've used `find` and not `find_all`, so there is no need to index the first reuslt as in `y[0]`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
x = soup.find('tr')
y = x.find('td', attrs={'class': 'blah'})
return len(y)>0 # or assert len(y)>0
```

Comment: Is there a way to do specifically using `assert`?

Comment: @JamesHallen just replace the `return` with `assert`

Comment: @JamesHallen it sounds like you're confused about what assert means, since you say in your question you want to _return_ true.

Comment: @JamesHallen I changed it so it shows both options. Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `left` has the key `class` then

```
return True if 'blah' in left['class'] else False
```

if this assumption does not always hold, you can mangle it with

```
return True if 'class' in left and 'blah' in left['class'] else False
```

but things are getting ugly.

If you use `assert`, you will throw an exception when this condition is not true (and not return any value). If that is what you really want;

```
 assert('blah' in left['class'])
 return True
```

will evaluate your `assert` and either throw the exception, or progress and return `True`. This is equivalent to;

```
 if 'blah' in left['class']:
     return True
 else:
     raise AssertionError('blah not in left["class"]')
```

Comment: If I use  `if 'blah' in left['class']:
     return True
 else:
     raise AssertionError('blah not in left["class"]')` would there be a probelm if left[0] does not contain a class attribute. I'm getting an error `return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'class'`

Comment: Yes, this does assume that `left` has the key `class`. If unsure, try the `assert` followed by the `return True` bearing in mind that you will never return `False` (or the alternative one-liner above)

Comment: But, I would get the same error when I try to implement `assert('prodSpecAtribute' in left['class'])` when the contents in left are not of class attribute, right?

Comment: I think this line works better: `return True if 'class' in left and 'blah' in left['class'] else False`

Comment: If you *want* to see errors, use `assert` if you want to return bools, use the one-liner you mentioned. Different tools for different jobs you see.